# gzip and minify server route response in meteor and iron-router

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, httpresponse, iron-router

I used Meteor and Iron-router and set many server route to return some HTML with Node.js response object.

Now I want to **minify** and also enable **gzip** in response.
How to do this?

This is my route code:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
    var res = this.response;
    var html =  "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
        "<html>\n" +
        "    <head>\n" +
        "    </head>\n" +
        "    <body>\n" +
        "        test\n" +
        "    </body>\n" +
        "</html>";
    res.end(html);
}, { where: 'server' });
```

This is page result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        test
    </body>
</html>
```

I want minified version like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>test</body></html>
```

I deploy test project in this URL:

http://gzipminify.meteor.com/

And you can test gzip support with [this tools](http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php).

Comment: You should use nginx in front of your Node app for this : https://www.yauh.de/do-i-really-need-nginx-with-my-meteornode-js-app/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor already gzips and minifies (in production mode) your app.

Just not to cause the confusion your main app file the *root file* available at xxx.meteor.com is not impacted by this (the one containing the HTML similar to index.html).

Also this index.html *LIKE* file is the bare one containing the references to your js & css files. The actual js file containing your app's HTML is indeed gzipped too.

The rest of your static assets (css, js, images, etc) are all gzipd.

In production mode your css & js are also minified.

Your site at gzipminify.meteor.com has no static assets nor CSS.

On the other hand

Is the web page compressed : YES  for http://test.meteor.com/5166d4fcc07e1605cbe979ef217942271d8badac.js

Is the web page compressed: NO for (http://test.meteor.com)

For a custom server side rendered route with iron router you can gzip files by including middleware with `Router.onBeforeAction` instead of `app.use` with the compression middleware of your choice (nodejs).

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I learn many things about gzip condition in meteor from your answer, but what about minification?? How to minify my html result when I used response object myself rather than normal meteor functionality?

Comment: @b24 The html is a static resource. Meteor minifies these on the build process. It may not be worth minifying them 'on-demand' as this is wasteful of your server's resources. Minify the string in `var html` in your source code before you put it in production. This way it doesn't have to be minified on every single request.

Comment: Yes it's right but above code just a sample. My `var html` content is dynamic and I can't minify this before production. I need an automatic solution to minify my response because meteor dosen't minify this.

Comment: @b24 you could store the raw html in the `private` directory in the root of your project and access it using `Assets.getText()`. You could use the npm module `html-minifier` to minify the files perhaps? There is unfortunately no 'meteor' solution as official server side rendering is still on the roadmap @ http://roadmap.meteor.com

Comment: html-minifier is awsome and working well for me. Thanks.